# Can't get out of this loop

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to get out of this loop. I want the loop to continue until the monster or the player is dead. I've tried getting rid of some of the `game_running == True` statements, but I don't know if that is proper. Should I get rid of the `game_running == True`? Any help would be great.

```
while game_running == True:
    counter = 0 
    new_round = True
    player = {'name': 'player','attack': 13, 'heal': 16, 'health': 100} 
    monster = {'name': 'Goblin',  'attack_min': 10, 'attack_max':20 ,'health': 100}   

    print('---' * 7)
    print('Enter Player name')
    player['name'] = input()   

    print(player['name'] +  ' has ' + str(player['health']) + ' health')
    print(monster['name'] +  ' has ' + str(monster['health']) + ' health')   

    while new_round == True:

        counter = counter + 1

        player_won = False
        monster_won = False

        print('---' * 50)
        print('Please select action')
        print('1) Attack')
        print('2) Heal')

        player_choice = input()

        if player_choice == '1':
            monster['health']  = monster['health'] - player['attack']
            if monster['health'] <= 0:
                player_won = True

            else:
                player['health'] = player['health'] - calculate_monster_attack(monster['attack_min'], monster['attack_max'])
                if player['health'] <= 0:
                    monster_won = True

        elif player_choice == '2':
            player['health'] = player['health'] + player['heal']

            player['health'] = player['health'] - calculate_monster_attack(monster['attack_min'], monster['attack_max'])                                                             
            if player['health'] <= 0:
                monster_won = True

        else:
            print('Invalid input')

        if player_won == False and monster_won == False:
            print(player['name'] + ' has '  + str(player['health']) + ' left')
            print(monster['name'] + ' has '  + str(monster['health']) + ' left')

        elif monster_won:
            print("You die... Please play again soon!")
            game_running == False

        elif player_won:
            game_running == False
            print("You beat the monster!")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you use `while True:` and then use `break` when you want to exit the loop.

Comment: @CDJB You removed the relevant code when you edited, why?

Comment: @Barmar The code was improperly indented; did I miss something?

Comment: @CDJB You deleted a block of code from the original post

Comment: Ah I see now! Whoops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` tests equality. `=` is for assignment. The places where you have `game_running == False` should be `game_running = False`

Tip: the places of the code where you have `if game_running == True` can simply be replaced with `if game_running`

Comment: An editor removed some of the code from the original post, tsk tsk

Comment: Someone edited the code and deleted this part.

Comment: Errors like this should just be closed as typos.